# How can i increment the decimal value by 0.1 every time inside a Test step counter in Java?

Tags: java, string, logging, log4j, decimalformat

I am working on a test automation framework using selenium. I am printing the Test steps on console:-

```
 like TEST STEP 6:- The testRun() methods has been called.
    then the sub-tests i want like this:
             TEST STEP 6.1 : run1() is called
             TEST STEP 6.2 : run2() is called
             TEST STEP 6.3 : run3() is called
             TEST STEP 6.4 : run4() is called
             ...................

Log("TEST STEP " + TestClass.stepCounter + "." + UtilitiesClass.decimalCounter);
```

The problem is that i am not able to do that without appending a dot(.) in the string? Can i use BigDecimal or DecimalFormat class?

Are there other ways in Java API to achieve the same result?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I fail to understand what you're asking. Would you like to remove the dot in "6.1", "6.2", etc. and thus have instead "61, "62" etc?

Comment: No, i want the sub-test steps to be printed on eclipse console: like 6.1, 6.2, 6.3 ...etc.